# How do i play different sounds on button click based on its enabled and disabled state

Tags: wpf

I have a button and when user clicks on it. I want to play different sounds based on its enabled and disabled state. I also want to do this at control level so that it can be reused across the application

Below is the current code which works fine when enabled. How do i play sound when it is disabled

```
<Button Width="100" Height="60" Content="Click">
   <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                    <SoundPlayerAction Source="Sounds/LogOnSuccessful.wav" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style> 
</Button>
```

Comment: How do you disable the `Button`? Or how do you define its state?

Answer (score 1):

A control doesn't get mouse events when it's disabled. That's what "disabled" means.

But when it's disabled, the visual parent will get a PreviewMouseDown event, if the parent gets any mouse events at all. So we can just wrap the Button in a Grid, have the Grid play the "disabled" state sound.

It's a little bit ugly. I'm sure there's a cleaner-looking way to do this: Maybe you could write a Behavior that you attach to the Button, and when attached it creates the Grid and inserts it in between the Button and its immediate parent. But I just tested this and it works.

The only concern in my mind is that the preview mouse down event always goes to the parent. On my Windows 10 machine here, only one sound gets played at a time and I don't get the parent sound, so in practice it's a non-issue -- on this machine, testing my little test project right now. If necessary, you could give the grid an event that checks if the button is enabled.

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox
        Content="Enable"
        x:Name="EnableCheckBox"
        />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <SoundPlayerAction Source="Sounds/LogOnFailed.wav" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Button
            x:Name="Button"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnableCheckBox}"
            Content="Button"
            >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                            <SoundPlayerAction Source="Sounds/LogOnSuccessful.wav" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives the solution to approach disabled button cick